# How to create route with different modules with same name?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I have 2 different models: category and page. My schema.yml:

```
propel:
  wiki_category:
    id:           ~
    address:      { type: varchar(255) }
    name:         { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    text:         { type: longvarchar }

  wiki_page:
    id:           ~
    category_id:  { type: integer, foreignTable: wiki_category, foreignReference: id, required: true}
    address:      { type: varchar(255) }
    name:         { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    text:         { type: longvarchar, required: true }
```

My routing.yml:

```
category_show:
  url:     /:address.:sf_format
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: WikiCategory, type: object }
  param:   { module: category, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: category, action: index }
page_show:
  url:     /:address/:address
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: WikiPage, type: object }
  param:   { module: page, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }
```

I want to make a route like `/:address`(from category)`/:address`(from page)

Is there any way to do this?

The idea is to make a page of categories with links to pages from this category. By pressing link executes action show of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two field with the same name, Propel won't be abble to understand wich one (from `/:address/:address`) is the one to use to get a `WikiPage` object.

The first *easiest* option is to rename one `address` inside your schema. Like `address_page` for `wiki_page`, so you will be able to have a route like this `/:address/:address_page` and Propel will know how to retrieve a `WikiPage` object

**But I will recommend you this second option.**

Do not use class `sfPropelRoute` to retrieve your object. Use `sfRequestRoute` instead. And then, you can give what ever name you want for parameter. Something more explicit like: `/:address_category/:address_page`:

```
page_show:
  url:     /:address_category/:address_page
  class:   sfRequestRoute
  param:   { module: page, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }
```

Then, inside the action, you must retrieve the object manually:

```
$wikiPage = WikiPageQuery::create()
  ->filterByAddress($request->getParameter('address_page'))
  ->leftJoin('WikiPage.WikiCategory')
  ->where('WikiCategory.address = ?', $request->getParameter('address_category'))
  ->findOne();
```

Just to let you know what sfPropelRoute does (basically):

- try to retrieve an object using request parameter & routing configuration
- if it can't find the object redirect to 404

In your case, you already retrieved object, you now just need to forward to 404 if it doesn't exist:

```
$this->forward404Unless($wikiPage);
```

Comment: class sfPropelRequest doesn't exist.  sfWebRequest?

Comment: @briancheg which version of symfony & propel are you using?

Comment: symfony 1.4.20 , propel default from symfony package

Comment: @briancheg Oh I see, an old Propel package then. Can you update to the most up to date one ? (which backward compatible with your version) https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin